# Facebook Puzzle(Probability)

Tags: facebook, algorithm, probability

Below is one of the facebook puzzle:
I am not able to understand how to proceed for this.

You are given C containers, B black balls and an unlimited number of white balls. You want to distribute balls between the containers in a way that every container contains at least one ball and the probability of selecting a white ball is greater or equal to P percent. The selection is done by randomly picking a container followed by randomly picking a ball from it.

Find the minimal required number of white balls to achieve that.

INPUT

The first line contains 1 <= T <= 10 - the number of testcases.

Each of the following T lines contain three integers C B P separated by a single space 1<= C <= 1000; 0 <= B <= 1000; 0 <= P <= 100;

OUTPUT

For each testcase output a line containing an integer - the minimal number of white balls required. (The tests will assure that it's possible with a finite number of balls)

SAMPLE INPUT

```
3 
1 1 60 
2 1 60 
10 2 50
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
2 
2 
8
```

EXPLANATION

In the 1st testcase if we put 2 white balls and 1 black ball in the box the probability of selecting a white one is 66.(6)% which is greater than 60%

In the 2nd testcase putting a single white ball in one box and white+black in the other gives us 0.5 * 100% + 0.5 * 50% = 75%

For the 3rd testcase remember that we want at least one ball in each of the boxes.

Comment: Why are we putting any black balls in boxes? Then we could always have just one ball in each box and always attain the probability. In the current problem definition I'm not seeing why that's not possible.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Probably we have to place all of the black balls.

Comment: It looks like this might work: distribute the blacks as evenly as possible, then add whites until you meet the required probability. For a given arrangement, the probability is `P = (1 / numContainers) * (pW(1) + pW(2) + ... + pW(numContainers))`, where `pW(i) = probability of picking a white ball from container i`. I don't have a proof however.

Comment: @IVlad I think that fails for 2 containers, 8 black balls, and 21% minimum.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Were you thinking of putting all the black balls (or at least a single one) in one container and a single white ball in another? Because that gives me a 50% probability.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe I actually misread the question and was thinking of a 3-5 split, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do the following:

Initial no. of white balls Nw = 1.

1. Given the number of white balls, Nw, find the configuration that gives the maximum probability of picking a white ball.
2. Check if this probability is greater than P.
3. If yes, then Nw is your answer, else, increment Nw and goto 1.

Ofcourse the challenge is to find the best configuration in Step 1.

EDIT: The problem now boils down to given W white balls, B black balls, and C containers, find the configuration that gives the maximum probability of picking a white ball.

```
P = ( w1/(w1+b1) + w2/(w2+b2) + ... + wc/(wc+bc) ) /c.
Max(P) = Max ( w1/(w1+b1) + w2/(w2+b2) + ... + wc/(wc+bc) )
Given: summation(wi) = W, summation(bi) = B, wi + bi >= 1
```

I am guessing that the configuration shall be such that if there are N containers having white balls, then atleast N-1 shall have only 1 white ball and no black balls and at most 1 container shall have both white balls and black balls. Just a guess though...